# AccessDeniendException on copying from GCP Compute instance to Storage bucket

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to copy an object from a GCP Compute instance to a Google Storage Bucket using `gsutil cp`. Both belong to the same owner (me) and to the same project. I want to automate the whole machine so authenticating manually is not what I want.

I have activated the [necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil) to use a service account on a Compute instance (details below) but when I try to `gsutil cp` a file to the bucket, I get an `AccessDeniedException`.
The error message complains about missing `storage.object.create` or `storage.object.list` permissions depending on if my bucket target path ends in a folder (`gs://<bucket>/test/`) or file (`gs://<bucket>/test.txt`).

What I did to get permissions (I have already tried a *lot*, including creating redundant custom roles which I also assigned to the service account):

- Start the instance:

```
gcloud instances create <instance> [...] \
    --service--account <name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --scopes cloud-platform,storage-full
```

- Give the service account permissions on creation.
- Give the service account permissions afterwards as well (just to be safe):

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project> \
    --member serviceAccount:<name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/storage.objectAdmin
```

- Edit Storage bucket permissions for the service account:

```
gsutil iam ch \
    serviceAccount:<name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectAdmin \
    gs://<bucket>
```

- Edit Storage bucket access control list (owner permission):

```
gsutil acl ch -u <name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:O gs://<bucket>
```

- At some point enabled bucket-level IAM policies instead of per-object policies (just to be safe).
- On the instance, use
  `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <key>.json` to authenticate the account.

However, no matter, what I do, the error does not change and I am not able to write to the bucket. I *can*, however, read files from the bucket.
At this point I am just wasting money trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new service account and executed the exact same steps... Now it works.